# "No tasks have started yet" for a Spark Job containing repartition()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

After scratching my head on the "NO tasks have started yet" for a **pyspark** job for some time, the issue has been isolated as:

Works:

```
ssc = HiveContext(sc)
sqlRdd = ssc.sql(someSql)
sqlRdd.collect()
```

Adding in the repartition() and it hangs "No Tasks have started yet":

```
ssc = HiveContext(sc)
sqlRdd = ssc.sql(someSql).repartition(2)
sqlRdd.collect()
```

This is on 1.2.0 bundled with CDH5